# Updating EJS Partial view data works, but data is not displayed

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, materialize

I am using NodeJS and EJS to build my application.

As the post title suggests, I have an index view into which I have inserted a modal partial view as such:

```
<%- include ./hint-modal %>
```

Initially, the **hints** variable I am trying to display in hint-modal is an empty array. Once the hints are computed, at the press of a button, I am sending a **PUT** request to Index, to update **hints**.

```
app.put(function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { hints: req.body.hints });
});
```

The code in hint-modal is:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < hints.length; i++) { %>
  <% console.log(hints[i]) %>
  <p><%= hints[i] %></p>
<% } %>
```

The console.log outputs each hint into the terminal. However, no paragraph is added to the view, and as such, not hint either.

I've been trying to figure out what's going on for the past couple of hours and have been looking at various solutions, but nothing worked. If anyone has any idea about it, it'd be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
The click handler is something along these lines, abstracting irrelevant calls to the issue at hand:

```
$('#hint-button').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/hints',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            in    : inLab,
            out   : outLab,
            undec : undecLab,
            unlab : unlab,
            sol   : solutions
        }),
        success: function(data) {
            var ret   = JSON.parse(data);
            var hints = ret.hints
            $.ajax({
                url         : '/',
                type        : "PUT",
                contentType : 'application/json',
                data        : JSON.stringify({ hints: hints})
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: The code you've posted works fine, it'd be necessary to see more code to see what the problem is here. Are you sure the html is not there (maybe it's just not visible for whatever reason)?

Comment: I've used the inspect element for the modal view, the paragraph tags do not get added when I press the button, even though the hints get output to the console. So yeah, other than the static HTML of the partial view, nothing else is there

Comment: Ahhh....wait, if i get it right, you press a button, make an ajax call and...why should anything be rendered at all? The way you've set this up you probably have to inject the response html yourself. Again, you need to post more code, specifically, your click handler and client put request.

Comment: Better update the question, don't post code in the comments

Comment: Done, don't know what I was thinking. The rendering is just so the initial hints variable gets updated with the current value

Comment: As I thought, you're making a `put` but you don't even have a success callback for that request defined to get the response data. Making that request won't update anything, that's not how things work.

Comment: I see what you mean, the view doesn't actually get an update hints variable. I've now added a success and an error callback and the hints variable in the partial view is still an empty array. Guess I'll head back to trying to update it. Thank you!